# Is there a best day of the week for offering a bounty in MathOverflow?

Tags: discussion, bounty, statistics

I'm thinking that the weekend is not a good time to offer a bounty because people are less likely to be at work.  So fewer people get to see the offer before it expires.

Comment: You know that a question with a bounty is displayed for 7 days in the featured tab on the main site, right? The time of offering a bounty influences mainly when the question is bumped to the frontpage - but bounty is definitely not the only thing which can bump a question. After offering the bounty the question stays among featured question for one whole week.

Comment: Just to clarify, what is exactly what you expect as an answer for this question? Percentage of questions with accepted answers depending on the day of the week when the bounty was offered? Average number of answers depending of the day of the week when the bounty was offered? I guess something like that should be possible to do using [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info).

Comment: My SQL skills are not very good, but I have tried to made at least some very basic queries and asked in the [SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1223/2018/12/14) for further advice. If somebody is interested in making SEDE queries, you can also join us in that room.

Comment: It is not that clear whether this correlates with the days when more people view the site - I suppose it might be more complicated than that. But since you mentioned days when "people are less likely to be at work", I'll add a link to a previous post where one of the answer shows at least some data about traffic: [the number of on line users at a given moment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3356).

Answer (score 2):

Probably various statistics about this can be found - and it all depends a bit on how you define *best time*. I have tried to make at least some queries using [Data Explorer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info). (Notice that it is possible to change the site in the queries, so you can compare the stats with some other sites.) Since I am pretty sure that there are many users on this site with great SQL skills, I am making this post [community wiki](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/community-wiki/info) - feel free to add some other queries if you have something interesting to share.

- [Percentage of bounties with accepted answer depending on the day when the bounty started](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/946112/percentage-of-bounties-with-accepted-answer-depending-on-the-day-when-the-bounty) ([graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/946112/percentage-of-bounties-with-accepted-answer-depending-on-the-day-when-the-bounty#graph))
- [Average number of answers depending on day when bounty was started](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/946110/average-number-of-answers-depending-on-day-when-bounty-was-started) ([graph](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/946110/average-number-of-answers-depending-on-day-when-bounty-was-started#graph))

It might be useful to know that in SQL `DATEPART("weekday", date) returns number which corresponds to Sunday = 1, Monday = 2, ..., Friday = 6, Saturday = 7.